# Copy a list of files preserving directory structure, without scripts

Tags: command-line, unix, cygwin

Is there a way to copy a list of files, that share a common base directory, preserving their relative directory structure? The files with relative paths are listed in a text file. 
**edit** I have the filenames listed in a plain text file.

I'd like to do this *without* using a script (no bash/batch/python/ruby/lua/etc.), similar to how `wget -i` works for urls. (My reason is that it'd give overhead/non-standard solution for a reasonably common task.)

I've tried `cat list.txt | xargs -I % cp % new_folder` from [Copy list of files](https://superuser.com/questions/180251/copy-list-of-files) but it didn't preserve the relative directory path.

I'd do this to export my selection of files (that I already have in a text file) from a directory structure that has big number of files (happens from time to time).

Comment: another reason for using a stand-alone command instead of custom scripts is that programs tend to be installed already or have packages/installers that can be found on the net by remembering the program's *name* alone, while having to write it again each time or taking your own scripts everywhere somehow feels less of benefit (even if you have no problems with your skills).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*tar cvf **-** ./filesAndDirecotries | (cd targetDirectory ; tar xvf **-**  )*

TAR (Tape Archive is old command to create an archive file) can write to stdin ( " - " parameter for the file ) and pipe and read from stdin in the second directory.

Above command first creates a tar file and writes to stdin and piped to a shell and change directory and untar the file by reading it from stdin.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my question that I tried to use a text file listing the filenames, and looking for an option to use that text file from a program that can copy. This solution however is very nice, and led me in the right direction because I think this can be done via the `-T` switch: `-T, --files-from F: get names to extract or create from file F`

Comment: I'll accept this as this came the closest to what I had in mind and set me on the right track. I've edited the question to pinpoint the existence of the text file. You can update your answer if you want. Finally I've used `tar cvf - -T filelist.txt | tar xvf - -C newdir`

Answer (score 5):

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/668094/129520) of [unixUser](https://superuser.com/users/268581/unixuser) set me on the right track. Turns out that `tar` can do both reading file and directory names from a text file with `-T`, and can even change directory with `-C`:

```
tar cvf - -T filelist.txt | tar xvf - -C newdir
```

This answers the question I had.

---

sources

To *obtain this information* from the *idea unixUser gave me*, I've [ducked for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tar+files+from+a+text+file) *tar files from text file*, leading to *trpn*'s (Q) and *Tinkster*'s (A) [conversion on linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/tar-from-contents-of-a-text-file-154721/). Simultaneously checking the [tar manual page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tar1.html) for any option that has something to do with *file*, both search led to the `-T` switch! To avoid relying on shell for changing directory, I've also [searched](https://blog.mozilla.org/metrics/2011/08/25/do-90-of-people-not-use-ctrlf/) it for any *directory* related options and found the `-C` switch. -- I see that `tar` is probably *the* command meant for grouping (copies of) files in many ways.

With this, one can use some tar binary without* relying on scripting. Just amazing how useful tar is.

---

(*: out of **preference**: I find bash/perl/python/whatever a *too general* tool for this *quite exact* task. However, as [pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/667995/copy-a-list-of-files-preserving-directory-structure-without-scripts/668303#comment844751_668014) by [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity), pipes are convenient - [without them](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=56149) one should be forced to create an intermediate file, eg. `tar cvf intermediate.tar -T filelist.txt` and `tar xvf intermediate.tar -C newdir`.)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your given example already uses bash. And that's exactly why the shell is scriptable in the first place – it's such a simple task that there is no need for a dedicated tool/program *just for it.*

```
cat list.txt | xargs -n1 dirname | sort | uniq | xargs -I% mkdir -p new_folder/%
cat list.txt | xargs -I% cp % new_folder/%
```

Or:

```
cat list.txt | while read path; do
    mkdir -p "new_folder/${path%/*}" && cp "$path" "new_folder/$path"
done
```

Or:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -I% install -Dm0644 % new_folder/%
```

Or:

```
cat list.txt | while read path; do
    install -Dm0644 "$path" "new_folder/$path"
done
```

(`install` is shorter but does not preserve modes, unfortunately.)

Comment: you are right about bash, but I've made the distinction on the basis that introducing control flow and variables really is an overkill for this and the more dependency you introduce the more dependent the solution on the platform is. I'm not happy with the string substitution either but that was the closest example I got. On the other hand, most platforms have understands a pipe, so it is a smaller dependency. Your first solution that fixes the example comes closest, thanks!

Comment: Well, there are platforms that easily run Perl but don't have bash nor xargs (Windows) nor even easily-usable pipes (VMS).

Comment: Right again. I suppose I've tried to explain a preference of mine. On the other hand, the `tar` command seems to suit my needs; I wasn't aware it had a `-T` switch. I think it's good to have these options available just like here and your answer also explains how this is normally done.

Comment: On the other hand, I should make myself more familiar with VMS. I never used it but wouldn't thought it lacks pipes. I wonder what VMS can use here because these ones also use pipes. May it solely rely on scripting? (on Windows, there is [unxutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html), [cygwin](http://cygwin.com), [msysgit's environment](http://msysgit.github.io/) and [so on](http://alternativeto.net/software/gow/), to provide familiarity/features)

Comment: @naxa: Nah, VMS is mostly dead. Although it seems that its command line interface does have support for pipes in the later versions (the [`PIPE`](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/9996/9996pro_155.html) keyword), but it was most definitely not designed for it – in comparison, even the Windows CLI is more Unix-like.