# How do I copy files from a list to another location, while preserving their directory structure?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I'm using Windows 7, but [Copy a list of files preserving directory structure, without scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/667995/copy-a-list-of-files-preserving-directory-structure-without-scripts) is exactly what I want to do.

I thought of making a batch file along the lines of

copy e:\foo.txt p:\foo.txt

but I'd like a more elegant solution with a single command.

Comment: Some members mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Try ROBOCOPY. Read the help

Comment: Also, look at `xcopy`: you can see all the options with `xcopy /?`. If there is a file listing the files to copy, you can combine it with a `for` command.