# Usage of the percentile operator in shell scripts

Tags: linux, unix, shell, tcsh

In this link: 
https://superuser.com/a/180252/401901

The following command is used:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -I % echo cp % new_folder
```

What does the `% %` usage mean?

All google search results are about using it in a modulo operation. Or, am I searching it in a wrong way?

Also, is there a name for this kind of usage?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From `man xargs`:

> ```
>    -I replace-str
>           Replace  occurrences  of  replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read
>           from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items;  in‐
>           stead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
> ```

So it sets up `%` to be the part of the command which is replaced by the list of files.

Comment: Yep. This %-sign isn't some kind of shell operator, it's just being used by xargs as a placeholder string so xargs knows where to insert the strings that are being piped in via stdin. When I use xargs, I usually use "HERE" as my string for -I or -J, which makes it more clear that it's just a string to tell xargs to "insert the input right HERE in this command line".